# background upload of images to S3 with Paperclip and Delayed Jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, delayed-job

I'm building an API for mobile apps which supports image uploading, using Paperclip.
Paperclip is set with S3 storage and its working fine.

I want to do the uploading from the server to S3 in the background using Delayed Jobs (the app will be hosted on Heroku).

Trying something such as @user.delay.photo = File.open(...), the result are errors by Delayed Jobs

```
UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET "last_error" = '{uninitialized stream
```

how can I do the background uploading ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is IO objects cannot be marshal and retrieve it back easily.

Using `.delay` method, it tries to dump the object into database records and pull it back when processing the job. Doing this way, make the record is big and brittle.

Better use the [custom job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#custom-jobs) instead if you have a lot of things to do in the job.

```
class UploadJob < Struct.new(:user_id)
  def perform
    user = User.find(user_id)
    user.photo = File.open(.....)
  end
end

Delayed::Job.enqueue UploadJob.new(@user.id)
```

You could do yourself by writing the image to the tmp directory in the project and reference in from the job. Last do a clean up when the job is finished.

Or, you could try this gem: [delayed_paperclip](https://github.com/jstorimer/delayed_paperclip) which is more handy.

Comment: the photo is in params[:photo], how do I pass it to the delayed job ? Struct.new(:user, :photo) and user.photo = photo doesn't seem to work

Comment: params[:photo] is a file that have been uploaded?

Comment: it's the image part of a multipart/post form.
user.photo = params[:photo] works without delayed jobs (with Paperclip)

Comment: thanks, I marked the answer as accepted, do you know how to use delayed_paperclip just for background uploading of the image ?

Comment: uploading is a process which the user sends the file to the server. I think it is not possible to do that. At the time, the file arrives it triggers rails and goes into the controller already. We can only do further background process after uploading such as resizing, upload to s3, ....

Comment: I meant background uploading to S3, this is what I'm trying to do